# I want to check whether URL exists or not in Synchronous way in javascript NODE.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

---

Guys i am new to the node js

Thank u guys 
.

```
const urlExist = require("url-exist");

 var httpUrl='';
 for (var i=0; i<req.body.url.length; i++) {
        httpUrl = req.body.url[i];
        let exists1 = () => Promise.resolve(urlExist(httpUrl),httpUrl);

        Promise.all([exists1()]).then((resultArr)=>{
              console.log(resultArr[0],httpUrl)
        })
}
```

The input is given as a array from POSTMAN

```
{
    "urls":["http://www.wrong.com/","http://wrong.com/","http://example.com","http://example.com","http:/example.com","http:/example5.com"]

}
```

This the OUTPUT i am getting

```
true  http:/example5.com
false http:/example5.com
true  http://example5.com
true  http://example5.com
true  http://example5.com
false http://example5.com
```

The EXPECTED output is:-

```
false http://www.wrong.com/
false http://wrong.com/
true  http:/example.com
true  http:/example.com
true  http:/example.com
true  http:/example5.com
```

But the thing is this function reading only "HTTP:/example5.com" and not giving the same Boolean value

Thank you guys

Comment: `httpUrl = req.body.url[i];` <--- shared variable.... of course it will have issues

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to wrap it in promise and then use a promise all inside the loop. Simply doing this should work

```
const urlExist = require("url-exist");

const urls = ["http://www.wrong.com/","http://wrong.com/","http://example.com","http://example.com","http:/example.com","http:/example5.com"];

Promise.all(urls.map(async url => {
  const result = await urlExist(url);
  return {"status": result, url};
}))
  .then(res => console.log(res));
```

You can modify the output the way  you want. At the moment it is logging it as an array

Comment: could you tell how to return this result as a JSON data

Comment: @RAJENDRAH the `res` is a valid json if you see. It is array of objects.

Comment: yeah its absolutely right, but when i tried to return that its throwing error , instead of printing the object , i want to return to another function ,is it possible??, if so help please.

Comment: remove the `.then` and return the asd return in front of `Promise.all`. Now where you want to use it, either await or use then

Comment: actually i am passing urls from other function i want to return this results to one variable brother and sorry i didn't understand  this  - > remove the .then and return the asd return in front of Promise.all. Now where you want to use it, either await or use then

Comment: actually i am passing urls from other function i want to return this results to one variable brother and sorry i didn't understand this - > remove the .then and return the asd return in front of Promise.all. Now where you want to use it, either await or use then

Answer (score 0):

Also, please note that using `Promise.all` to execute multiple queries to the same url here is done *simultaneously*, hence maybe the weird result (server might refuse when being sent too many requests from the same IP for example).

If you want to avoid it, you could use `for ... of` loop which will execute each request one after another *sequentially*, like for example :

```
const exists = require('url-exist')

const urls = [
  'http://www.wrong.com/',
  'http://wrong.com/',
  'http://example.com',
  'http://example.com',
  'http:/example.com',
  'http:/example5.com'
]

const run = async () => {
  const results = []
  for (const url of urls) {
    try {
      const result = await exists(url)
      results.push({ result, url })
    } catch (e) { console.error(`error with ${url} : ${e}`) }
  }
  return results
}

run()
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.error)
```

Hope this helps! :)